# Add 1 month to part string date

Tags: php, date, datetime

wasnt sure how to best describe this.  I make an API call and one of the elements I get back is like the following

```
0 => array:3 [▼
    "customId" => "12345"
    "customName" => "Month"
    "customValue" => "June 16"
]
```

As you can see the customValue is June 16, meaning June 2016.  Is there any way I can add 1 month onto this, so to make it July 16?  I know I could simply replace Jun with July using something like str_replace, but I do not want to change the expression month on month.  What I am really looking for is to have the system understand that this is Jun 16 and 1 month needs adding onto it.

Would this be possible?

Thanks

Comment: be VERY careful doing this. what happens if you have `Jan 31` - what do you want +1 month to be? Feb 28? 29? Mar 1? Mar 2?

Comment: @MarcB its Mouth and Year (June 2016)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the value of `$monthAndDay`:

```
$monthAndDay = "June 16";
$monthAndDay = date("F j", strtotime($monthAndDay." + 1 month"));

echo $monthAndDay; //outputs July 16
```

---

Within an array:

```
$arr = [
    "customId" => "12345"
    "customName" => "Month"
    "customValue" => "June 16"
];

$arr["customValue"] = date("F j", strtotime($arr["customValue"]." + 1 month"));
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdmonthname.php
Look at this.
It could be a way to do it with this command!

Hope I could help,
   Skayo